# Why is the set ${1,x^2,x^3...}$ linearly independent as functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I know that the set is a basis for the vector space of polynomial over some fields. 
but why are they linearly independent?

namely, as function from the polynomial to the base field, what is a proof that they cannot be linearly dependent as functions?

Comment: Is it possible to express $x^n$ by a finite linear combination (i.e. the coefficients are scalars) of terms which does not include $x^n$?

Comment: You need to find a linear combination such that  $a+bx^2+cx^3=0$ for every x.

Comment: @Niing: "Because they're equally important": weird explanation !?

Comment: @Javi, that's the part I was having trouble to prove, as indeterminate, sure, it's not possible, but as functions, how do I know there does not exist such a finite linear combination? over any field? I was trying to show that if they equal at a particular value for x, then there exists another value for x where the equality would not hold, but that doesn't seem to work.  Another thing I could think of is that a n-th power polynomial would have to have n roots over the algebraic closure of the field.

Answer (score 5):

***Polynomial functions*** $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ over a field $K$ are linearly independent over $K$ if and only if $K$ is infinite.  This is because $$x^{|K|}-x=0$$ for every $x\in K$, when $K$ is finite.  In fact, every function from $K$ to $K$ is a polynomial function when $K$ is finite, and in this case, the best you can say is that $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{|K|-1}$ are linearly independent functions.

On the other hand, ***abstract polynomials*** $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ over $K$ (i.e., they are elements of $K[x]$) are always linearly independent over $K$ (you can prove this claim, for example, via [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)).  You have to distinguish between polynomial functions and abstract polynomials.  Only when $K$ is infinite, you can roughly treat the two concepts as the same thing.

Comment: It seems weird to me to invoke the Vandermonde determinant for abstract polynomials, given that the polynomial ring $K[X]$ has a basis given by $1,x^2,\dots$ basically by construction

Comment: It is true that you don't need to prove linear independence of $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ as it is the definition of $K[x]$, but some people will want a proof anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible answers:

- The abstract definition of a polynomial ring stipulates that a polynomial, with coefficients in $\mathbf R$, say, is a sequence $(a_0,a_1,\dots, a_k,\dots)$ with *finite support*, i.e. there is only a finite number of $k$s such that $a_k\ne 0$. This set is endowed with an addition, defined componentwise, and a product defined as the Cauchy product. It makes the set of polynomials an  $\mathbf R$-algebra, and a basis as an $\mathbf R$-vector space is made up of the powers of the particular polynomial $(0,1,0,\dots, 0\dots)$, usually denoted as $X$.

If $n$ is the largest $k$ such that $a_k\ne 0$ (the *degree* of the polynomial),  the polynomial $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,0,\dots, 0,\dots)$  can be rewritten as
$$a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_nX^n$$
so it is *by construction* that $a_0=a_1=\dots =a_n$.

- If there were a non-trivial  linear relation  between $1,x,\dots, x^n$:
  $$a_0+a_1x+\dots a_n x^n=0,$$
  the polynomial would have any value of $x$ as a root. However, this is impossible over an infinite field, as one shows  that a polynomial function $p(x)$ with coefficients in a field has  at most $\deg p$  roots.

Comment: I know. I said in the beginning of my answer the base field was $\mathbf R$. I'll add, for the second explanation,  it requires an infinite field.

Answer (score 2):

You are having trouble proving this because it's not true. Over the $p$ element field  the polynomial $x^p -x$ is identically $0$ as a function, so $\{x, x^p\}$ is a dependent set.

Those polynomials are in fact dependent over any finite field, since 
there are only finitely many functions from a set to itself and the list of formal powers $x^n$ is infinite.

Note: here is an answer to the narrower question suggested in the comments. In characteristic $p$ the polynomials $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{p-1}$ are independent as functions. If some linear combination produced the $0$ function that linear combination would be a polynomial of degree at most $p-1$ with at least $p$ roots (since thare are at least $p$ elements in the field) hence the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to that the set ${1,x^2,....x^{p-1}}$ where p is the characteristic of the base field.

Comment: The polynomial $x^p-x$ is identically zero on a field if and only if that field has $p$ many elements. It is not enough to require the characteristic to be $p$.